# Extract text from special link between brackets

Tags: php, hyperlink, extract

How to extract texts' links text from a string where links are between brackets:

For example:

```
$string = 'adorti sunt Montium primum [a href="https://..."]Link name[/a] divaricaturn sine spiramento ullo. post haec militares, [a href="https://..." class="ln-style-1"]blabla[/a].';
```

I need to get:

```
$result = 'adorti sunt Montium primum Link name divaricaturn sine spiramento ullo. post haec militares, blabla.'
```

**SOLUTION:**

Thanks to @Slava Rozhnev I found a way:

```
$result = str_replace('[/a]', '', preg_replace('/\[a.*?\]/', '', $string));
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service, you should know this.
You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and 
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Yes, sorry but I don't have a good command of regexp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use PHP [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function like this:

```
<?php
$string = 'adorti sunt Montium primum [a href="https://..."]Link name[/a] divaricaturn sine spiramento ullo. post haec militares, [a href="https://..." class="ln-style-1"]blabla[/a].';

$result = preg_replace(['/\[a.+\]/Umi','/\[\/a\]/Umi'], '', $string)

echo $result;
```